# DotNet Core Setup Failed

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows

When install DotNet Core on my windows 10 laptop(DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1),the runtime package setup failed.

I found some error information from the install log file:

web developer tool info:

```
[037C:1EC0][2016-06-19T11:07:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[037C:1EC0][2016-06-19T11:07:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[2E70:3228][2016-06-19T11:07:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[2E70:3228][2016-06-19T11:07:26]i319: Applied execute package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[2E70:3228][2016-06-19T11:07:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[037C:1EC0][2016-06-19T11:07:26]i318: Skipped rollback of package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[2E70:3228][2016-06-19T11:07:26]i319: Applied rollback package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14, result: 0x0, restart: None
[037C:1EC0][2016-06-19T11:07:26]i351: Removing cached package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{1F275091-F18D-37F3-8A70-8E6CE66BB1A8}v14.1.20512.0\
[037C:1EC0][2016-06-19T11:07:26]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22041006-8484-4b8d-a13c-40189695de2f}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[037C:1EC0][2016-06-19T11:07:26]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22041006-8484-4b8d-a13c-40189695de2f}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2E70:3228][2016-06-19T11:07:26]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 18):

Another Solution is to:

1. go to the folder where you have downloaded the installer
2. open the command prompt by Shift+right click -> Open command window here
3. Type - `dotnetcore.1.0.0-vs2015tools.preview2 SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1` and hit enter

This should skip the VS update check and start the installation normally.

Comment: I still have the same issue :(

Comment: @eg16 If you aren't doing so already, make sure you are running the command from a cmd or PowerShell window in Administrator mode.

Comment: What a charming little solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this issue by

1. turning off Antivirus
2. clearing the `%temp%` folder
3. running the DotNet Core (DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1) again in repair mode

Comment: Just clearing the `%temp%` folder helped me solve the same problem with installing the `.net core 5 runtime`

Answer (score 0):

After applying the other answers here the install was still failing for me.  Periodically during the install, a pop-up warning dialog would open stating "The account already exists".  I reviewed the *Programs and Features* list and saw 3 different entries for the VS2015Tools preview.  I right-click Uninstall'ed each of them (which removed each one almost immediately), and tried the install again.  This time it completed without errors.