# VisualStudio - Microsoft .Net Core 1.0.0.0, Set Up failed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, frameworks

I have installed VisualStudio 2015 but when i want to instal Asp.Net Core framework from  [dot.net](http://dot.net) website i get the following error:

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What does it say in the log file?

Comment: I am getting the same error after installing VS2015 update 3 + Xamarin + reSharper. Core templates are not available. My log file is too long but i get many lines like: `[11A0:04D0][2016-07-26T22:30:50]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1055'`

Comment: Try the following solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134048/problems-installing-dot-net-core-1-0-0-vs-2015-tools-preview-2
Run the installation with command line:
`D:\WhereverYourFileIs>"DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe" SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should help:

1. Go to the folder where you have downloaded the installer
2. Open the command prompt by `Shift + right click` -> `Open command window here`
3. Type - `dotnetcore.1.0.0-vs2015tools.preview2 SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1` and hit enter
   This should skip the VS update check and start the installation normally.

I have also answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909424/dotnet-core-setup-failed)

PS: If it still doesn't work, run command prompt **as administrator**

Comment: It still does not work. I have already installed VS2015 Update 3 and i get the same error.

Comment: @eg16 can you open the log file and try to find the error?

Comment: @CoOl run command prompt as administrator fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: This method worked for me following a fresh install of VS2015 with Update 3, thanks